# Sustituir una imagen por otras distintas cuando paso el ratón por encima - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

Estoy trabajando en una web y necesitaría conseguir el siguiente efecto al pasar el ratón sobre una imagen. Dejo aquí mi pregunta con la esperanza de que alguno me pueda ayudar. Gracias de antemano.
El material del que parto sería el siguiente:

- Imagen-estatica.gif
- Imagen-02.gif
- Imagen-03.gif
- Imagen-04.gif

La idea es que al pasar el ratón sobre una imagen fija, esta se sustituya por una imagen animada distinta cada vez (Imagen-02.gif, Imagen-03.gif, ...), y que a su vez, al sacar el ratón, esta vuelva a su estado inicial (imagen-estatica).

A continuación dejo una web de ejemplo donde se puede apreciar con claridad en el logo central el efecto que busco.

[Ejemplo que busco](https://magoz.is/)

He coseguido acercarme con el siguiente código, pero tan solo con una animación. Agradecería enormemente cualquier tipo de ayuda.

```
<img alt="animation" src="imagen-estatica.gif" width="65" height="65" onmouseover="this.src='imagen-02.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='imagen-estatica.gif'">
```

Muchísimas gracias desde ya.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta seria una forma que lo podrías hacer, declarando un array con los gifs los cuales irán cambiando a medida que aumente el contador cada que se ponga el mouse sobre la imagen de forma que no se repitan las imágenes, y reiniciándose cada que llegue a la máxima cantidad del array, lo cual lo manejas desde la condición `IF`, tambien cuentas con la función de restablecer que se ejecutara con el `mouseout` y pondrá la imagen inicial de nuevo.

```js
window.onload = function(){

   var cont = 0;
    var gifs = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif','https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8nZC.gif','https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/44/7b/0e447bcb092088c8bd09584b2c2dd833.gif']
   var element = document.querySelector('#gif');

   element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    change();
    if(cont < 2){
     cont++;
    }else{
     cont = 0;
    }
   });

   element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){

    restablecer();

   });

   function restablecer(){

    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://share.america.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_223131421.jpg')
   };


   function change(){

    element.setAttribute('src', gifs[cont]);

   };

  };
```

```html
<img src="https://share.america.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_223131421.jpg" alt="GIF" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" id="gif">
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta Santiago.
Es justo lo que estaba buscando. Funciona perfectamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un método que te cambie la imagen aleatoriamente cada que pones el ratón sobre tu imagen

y añadir a tu pagina

```js
window.onload = function(){

var imagen = document.getElementById('imgDinamica');
imagen.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
        //Sustituye el número 3 por el numero de imágenes dinámicas que necesites
        var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        
        switch(rnd){
         case 1:
           this.src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif';
           break;
         case 2:
           this.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8nZC.gif';
           break;
         case 3:         this.src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/44/7b/0e447bcb092088c8bd09584b2c2dd833.gif';
           break;
        }   
});

}
```

```html
<img alt="animation" id="imgDinamica" src="https://share.america.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_223131421.jpg" width="65" height="65" onmouseout="this.src='https://share.america.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/shutterstock_223131421.jpg';">
```

Esa respuesta solo es para esos nombres de imagen, en caso de que los nombres cambien y no sean numéricos utiliza el siguiente método

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta Ulises. Sin embargo, cuando desplazo el ratón encima de la imagen no me cambia la "imagen-estática". Es muy probable que esté metiendo yo la pata en algo. Igualmente. Muchísimas gracias. Seguiré intentándolo.