# Sustituir la imagen del fondo por otras distintas cuando paso el ratón por un texto definido

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Trabajo en una web de presentación y me gustaría que, al pasar el ratón sobre el nombre, se cambiase la imagen de fondo de a una estampada y que, al sacar el ratón, volviese el fondo original (blanco)

En otra pregunta de este foro se acercan bastante a lo que me gustaría, pero en este caso serían imágenes fijas de fondo y el activador sería pasar el ratón por el texto, no sobre las imágenes.

Este es el enlace a esa pregunta:
[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133149/sustituir-una-imagen-por-otras-distintas-cuando-paso-el-ratón-por-encima-javas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133149/sustituir-una-imagen-por-otras-distintas-cuando-paso-el-rat%C3%B3n-por-encima-javas)

En este caso yo tendría las imágenes en png.

Llamadas: fondo1.png, fondo2.png y así sucesivamente.

Por si sirve de ayuda, esto es lo que me gustaría. Tengo este texto y al pasar el ratón por el nombre cambiaría el fondo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

espero mi respuesta te sirva mucho.

Para cambiar el fondo detrás de un texto debes utilizar la función hover sobre el contenedor de dicho texto.

Si tienes un contenedor div

```
<div>
  <h1>Soy un elemento</h1>
</div>

En el código Css colocas:

div:hover{
   background-image:url(carpeta/nombre.jpg);
}
```

Al pasar el ratón por encima se colocará de fondo la imagen que has definido en la url.

Comment: Gracias por responder. El problema es que de ese modo solo se cambiaría por esa imagen definida y yo querría que variase entre varias imágenes. Una distinta cada vez que paso el ratón por encima.